# Is it possible to set up a PC as a terminal to a VM?

Tags: vdi

I have recently set up my own Dell server running ESXi with several Ubuntu virtual machines running, performing various tasks.

I have some older PCs (2-3 years old) around the house. I was wondering if it is possible to have a PC boot up and connect directly in to one of the Virtual Machines over the LAN?

So rather than having Windows or some other OS on the PC, there might some minimal OS, enough the open the desktop on a VM, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for any OS on the PC. Use PXE to boot and load the OS from a NFS share on the server, and have it use XDMCP to open a session in a VM.

Comment: Cool, Thank you. I don't know what XDMCP is, but I'll find out.